# How make a subdomain point towards Route 53?

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, amazon-route53

I have a sub-domain of a domain name. Say it is documentation.mycompany.com. The DNS records for mycompany.com and all it's subdomains are controlled by their current data centre provider.

I am setting up a static website for this organisation on AWS. This will have route 53 -> WAF -> Cloud Front -> S3 bucket and the S3 bucket will have all the JS or HTML inside it.

What entry should the hosting provider of mycompany.com make to their DNS servers to so that documentation.mycompany.com can point to route 53?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS have this documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigratingSubdomain.html).

1. Create a Route 53 hosted zone for the subdomain.
2. Get the current DNS configuration from the current DNS service provider for the parent domain.
3. Add records for the subdomain to your Route 53 hosted zone.
4. Update the DNS configuration with the DNS service provider for the parent domain by adding name server records for the subdomain.
5. Update the DNS configuration with the DNS service provider for the parent domain by adding name server records for the subdomain.

The linked AWS documentation links to further information that will give you details of each step.